# How to make a GET request from API with ngrx?(Angular 7)

Tags: rest, angular7, ngrx

How can I make a GET request from an API(any API) with ngrx(Angular 7 and Redux). I saw some articles from web but they are about Angular 2 or requests with Observables(rxjs). How to make it with ngrx? I created the model.

```html
/* Defines the events entity */
export interface Events {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    date: number;
}
```

the reducer

```html
import { Events } from '../models/events';
import { EventsActionTypes, EventsActions } from './events.actions';

// State for this feature (Event)
export interface EventState {
  events: Events[];
  error: string;
}

const initialState: EventState = {
  events: [],
  error: ''
};

export function reducer(state = initialState, action: EventsActions): EventState {

  switch (action.type) {

    case EventsActionTypes.Load:
      return {
        ...state,
        events: action.payload
      };

    

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

the actions

```html
import { Events } from '../models/events';

/* NgRx */
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';

export enum EventsActionTypes {
  Load = '[Events] Load'
}

// Action Creators

export class Load implements Action {
  readonly type = EventsActionTypes.Load;
}


// Union the valid types
export type EventsActions = 
  | Load;
```

effects

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap, map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { EventsService } from '../services/events.service';
import { Events } from '../models/events';

/* NgRx */
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Actions, Effect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import * as eventsActions from './events.actions';

@Injectable()
export class eventsEffects {

  constructor(private eventsService: EventsService,
              private actions$: Actions) { }

  @Effect()
  loadeventss$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(eventsActions.EventsActionTypes.Load),
    mergeMap(action =>
      this.eventsService.getEvents().pipe(
        map(events => (new eventsActions.LoadSuccess(events))),
        catchError(err => of(new eventsActions.LoadFail(err)))
      )
    )
  );

}
```

service

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {ApiService} from '../../core/services/base.services';
import {Events} from '../models/events'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class EventsService {

  private _eventsUrl="http://localhost:3000/api/events";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private apiService: ApiService) { }
  
  getEvents(){
      return this.apiService.get<Events[]>(this._eventsUrl, null, false, false);
  }


 private handleError(err) {
  // in a real world app, we may send the server to some remote logging infrastructure
  // instead of just logging it to the console
  let errorMessage: string;
  if (err.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
    // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
    errorMessage = `An error occurred: ${err.error.message}`;
  } else {
    // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
    // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
    errorMessage = `Backend returned code ${err.status}: ${err.body.error}`;
  }
  console.error(err);
  return throwError(errorMessage);
}

}
```

the functions from apiservice are

```html
 public getWithParams<T>(url:string, params: HttpParams | null, publishException: boolean=true, loadingEnabled:boolean=true): Observable<T>{
        const headers: HttpHeaders=this.generatecustomHeader(loadingEnabled);
        const options={params, headers};

        return this.manageErrors(this.httpClient.get<T>(url, options), publishException);
    }

    public get<T>(url: string, params?:any, publishException: boolean=true, loadingEnabled: boolean=true): Observable<T>{
        const httpParams: HttpParams=params?this.makeHttpParams(params): null;
        return this.getWithParams(url, httpParams,publishException, loadingEnabled);
    }
```

How can I make the connection with the API using the ngrx? I will appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NGRX Does not make API request. What NGRX does is give you a pattern so that when you make requests you can update your store efficiently.

From what can tell you have provided a ton of information here, but what your missing is your module that loads the store, so my example will be a little off

The examples you showed, already have most everything you want. If your goal is to now get events, you have to dispatch the event which will trigger your effect.

In your example above, you have an effect that retrieves your events it in pointing to an action that is not in your reducer. `eventsActions.LoadSuccess` needs to be registered to your reducer and replace `EventsActionTypes.Load`. Remember your only loading them, on success. The load action simply triggers the effect to go get them from your API.

Once you do that you are basically looking for something like this in your code.

`store.dispatch(new actions.Load());`

This will see the effect and then go out to your API to load from the server and then trigger the success action with all the events.

If you have updated your reducer, it will trigger on the success action and then load all your events into the store.